# Using PHP Constants and Functions to navigate file directory

Tags: php

PHP Version 5.6.40

Aim is to enable index page navigation to separate files such as header and footer contained within the following sub-directory files via the use of constants and functions in order to make site updates easier.

```
C:\wamp64\www\games_database\index.php
C:\wamp64\www\games_database\php\all_games.php
C:\wamp64\www\games_database\private\footer.php

header.php functions.php initialise.php
C:\wamp64\www\games_database\css\style.css
```

expected result:

```
C:\wamp64\www\games_database\php\all_games.php
```

actual result:

```
The requested URL /games_databasephp/all_games.php was not found on this server.
```

**Code used**

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('private/initialise.php');
?>
<?php 
include_once(PRIVATE_PATH . '/header.php');
?>
<main>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</main>
<?php
include_once(PRIVATE_PATH . '/footer.php');
?>
```

initialise.php

```
<?php
define("PRIVATE_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));
define("PROJECT_PATH", dirname(PRIVATE_PATH));
define("PUBLIC_PATH", PROJECT_PATH . 'php');
define("SHARED_PATH", PRIVATE_PATH . 'private');


$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/') + 15;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
require_once('functions.php');  
?>
```

all_games.php

```
<?php
require_once('private/initialise.php');
?>
<?php include_once(PRIVATE_PATH . '/header.php');?>
<main>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Game name </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Platform </td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Type </td>
           <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Released </td>
           <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</main>
<?php include_once(PRIVATE_PATH . '/footer.php');?>
```

functions.php

```
<?PHP
    function url_for($script_path){
    return WWW_ROOT . $script_path;
    }
?>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2019</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Games Database</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="<?php echo url_for('css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css">
</head> 
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Games Database</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('index.php'); ?>">Games Database</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Login/Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('php/all_games.php'); ?>">View All Games</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

methods used
 - Assigned file paths to PHP constants
 - Used **FILE**  to return the current path to this file
 - Used dirname() to return the path to the parent directory
 - Assigned the root URL to a PHP constant

I clearly do not fully understand how to fully implement constants and functions within PHP, and I suspect the issue is with the initialise.php file, in particular with this section of code

```
$public_end = strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/') + 15;
$doc_root = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, $public_end);
define("WWW_ROOT", $doc_root);
require_once('functions.php');
```

Comment: I cannot see any link. Btw. `__DIR__` constant is available as well.

Comment: Cannot see anything returned from the code.

Comment: _“The requested URL /games_databasephp/all_games.php was not found on this server.”_ - that is an error message generated by the web server, because it can not find anything matching this requested path and file. At this point, this does not even have anything to do with your includes/requires yet - they have not even come into play yet, the web server is not even executing your script.

Comment: Your `url_for` function neglected to insert a slash after the WWW_ROOT.

Comment: so its to do with my actual server settings then!

Comment: No, it is first and foremost to do with the fact that you linked to `/games_databasephp/all_games.php`, but probably meant to link to `/games_database/php/all_games.php`

Comment: Any advice on how to remedy this?

Comment: Well insert the missing / …?

Comment: if i add the missing / to the following link <li><a href="<?php echo url_for('php/all_games.php'); ?>">View All Games</a></li> it will just return the following error Warning: require_once(private/initialise.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\games_database\php\all_games.php on line 2.  i Know its the url_for that needs to be adjusted in some way just not sure exactly how or what!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that i needed to place an extra / within the the url_for().  I also neglected to place ../ at the start of all the links going back up a directory.
I foolishly thought that when I set up my initialise constraints and function that this would not be needed.

I humbly thank you all for your time and patience.